# Xcode Info.plist error: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';' but looks like valid XML

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

Why is Xcode giving me errors on my Info.plist file?
The first error is on the first line (which I had nothing to do with writing.)
The first line is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

and the error given is:

```
Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
```

If I hit the "Fix" button on the error message it inserts a ; right after "1.0" but I don't think this is right because the way I have it is how I see it in every online example. Plus it goes on to complain about '$' is not an identifier; use backticks to escape it. And fixing those causes more problems. Hopefully this makes sense to someone with more knowledge than me.

Comment: Hmm my code like didn't show up....
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: Is it possible that your Info.plist ended up in your compile sources list? (Project -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources)

Comment: I'm using XCode 9.2 and I don't see Project in the top line. Were you referring to my project specifically somehow? I also searched the XCode help for Build Phases and Compile Sources and it didn't seem to take me anywhere. Another odd thing I thought I would point out is that my Info.plist file shows up as XML code and not in the pretty editor that it used to be in and I don't know how to get back to that prettier view.

Comment: Ah I found what you were talking about. Under Tagets, Build Phases, Compile Sources. But Info.plist is not listed there. Only my ViewControllers and AppDelegate.swift files are listed there.

Comment: Is it possible that you're doing a `#include <Info.plist>` or something like that in your code?

Comment: I can't find an #include <Info.plist> anywhere in my files. Mostly its just import UIKit at the top of each file.

Comment: @PaulK. to open it in the pretty view, right-click the file in the Xcode navigator and select `Open As -> Property List`

Comment: Thank you! That let me change the view to the better looking one and then it no longer tried to compile the xml. Is it possible to mark a comment as the solution?